# How to loop an array using the value of an xml child node using PHP?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I'm new to PHP and in particularly XML.

I'm trying to pull data from an XML file using the particular values of one of the child nodes. All the online resources I seem to find lead me to how to get all the values from a child node but I want to pull only the ones that contain a certain value in a child node. I'm struggling to get the format of the if statement right.

Any help, much appreciated, thank you!

My code so far:

```
if( !($xml = simplexml_load_file('images/database.xml')) )
{
  echo "Unable to load XML file";
}
else
{
  foreach($xml->children() as $document)
  {
    if ($xml->$document->city == $xml->$document->city['London'])
    {
      echo $document->name . ", ";
      echo $document->description . ", ";
      echo $document->image . ", <br>";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `if($document->city == 'London') {` ???

Comment: You code works?

Comment: No, it works if write it as a foreach loop but as soon as I try and put an if condition it, I can't seem to get it to work

Comment: 1. Provide a small example of the XML please. That would allow people to reproduce your problem. 2. `$xml->$document` looks really wrong. 3. Check out `SimpleXMLElement::xpath()` and `DOMXpath::evaluate()`.